# Scrape Linkedin search result

Tags: selenium, xpath

Using Selenium, I want to perform a search on linkedin and get the links of posts from result.

But I'm stuck at finding xpath of links of posts. I can't find any link in DOM which represent the url of post.

What I fingured is just this: `//ul[contains(@class, 'search-result')] /li` which represents the posts from result.

Example of search result: https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/content/?keywords=stackoverflow&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER

Can you help me to figure an xpath of links of posts? Or a way to get the links of posts?

P.S.: I'm also open for other ways, like HTTP Requests. Not just Selenium.

Comment: I've checked into search results DOM and I couldn't find any link linked to those posts. Even if I open one, I can't see any link or API call done in browser's console.  Maybe you can find something here: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/2836/accessing-linkedin-apis?lang=en

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIn has internal API (Voyager), so you can use it to get results and parse them. Response is in json, but it is very complicated.

Here how you can make request to Voyager API for search results (proto):

```
from urllib.parse import quote
import requests

count = 10
query = 'coca cola'  #  TODO: Query to search
li_at = '{li_at from account cookie}' # TODO: Add cookie
cursor = 0  # Starts with 0, next can be acquired from responses


# Get results
search_query = '+'.join(quote(word) for word in query.split())  # Encoding search_query

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/search/blended?count={}&filters=List(sortBy-%3Edate_posted,resultType-%3ECONTENT)&keywords={}&origin=SORT_RESULTS&q=all&queryContext=List()&start={}'.format(
    count, search_query, cursor)

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",  # TODO
    "csrf-token": "ajax: 0",
    "x-restli-protocol-version": "2.0.0",
}
cookies = {'liap': 'true',
           'JSESSIONID': 'ajax: 0',
           'li_at': li_at
          }

r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, timeout=15)
response = r.json()

# Parse links
found_links = list()
for post in response['elements'][1]['extendedElements']:  # Here we got all posts with a lot of data
    action_types = post['update']['value']['com.linkedin.voyager.feed.render.UpdateV2']['updateMetadata']['actions']  # List of possible actions with post (for web-client)
    for action in action_types:  # We need to find RESHARE action - it contains full link to post
        if "SHARE_VIA" in action['actionType']:
            found_links.append(action['url'])
            
# Results
print(found_links)
```

You need to correct User_Agent (or use mine) and 'li_at' cookie from your account.

Results will be sorted by date.

Comment: Thank you. And also thank you for code, but I don't understand very much from it, because I use java. Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: I have edited code, now with logic for parsing post links from query results. You just need to add li_at cookie from linkedin account (you can find it in F12 tools in firefox\chrome. You need only li_at cookie, not all of them) and of course edit query :)

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I wrote the code in java with exact values you said, but I get as answer this `code: 403 - reason: Forbidden - body: CSRF check failed.`

Comment: It seems like header ```"csrf-token": "ajax: 0" ``` hasn't been added to request.

Comment: I have tested with Postman and get same error. And I'm 100% sure `csrf-token` with value `ajax: 0` is not missing from headers

Comment: They do not have some documentation for this link? I can't find it.

Comment: Remove the double quotes which are passed in the `csrf-token`. This causes the CSRF check failed issue :)

Comment: @MadRay Thanks I tried your code and it worked but I also wanna scrape comments, Now the json response I'm getting does have comments but they are limited and not all comments appear. Do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: @WahabAftab, i haven't tried comment crawling yet. As far as i remember, additional requests required for crawling comments to another api endpoint - https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/feed/comments